# jQuery Animations not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have a td element with attribute onclick='edit(this)'.
Everything in this script works fine, except when I try to execute alerts() when a non space or numerical character is typed, absolutely nothing happens to the  element.

```
<script>
    function edit(s) {
        if(s.innerHTML != "&nbsp;" && s.innerHTML != "<nobr name=\"clear\">&nbsp;</nobr>") {
            s.innerHTML = "<input onblur='set(this)' id ='select' type='text' value='"+ s.innerHTML[19] +"'>";
        }
        else{
            s.innerHTML = "<input onblur='set(this)' id ='select'type='text'>";
        }
        document.getElementById('select').focus();
    }
    function set(s) {
        if(s.value == "" || (s.value != "1" && s.value != "2" && s.value != "3" && s.value != "4" && s.value != "5" && s.value != "6" && s.value != "7" && s.value != "8" && s.value != "9")){
            if(s.value != "1" && s.value != "2" && s.value != "3" && s.value != "4" && s.value != "5" && s.value != "6" && s.value != "7" && s.value != "8" && s.value != "9") {
                s.parentNode.innerHTML = "<nobr name='clear' id='alert'>&nbsp</nobr>";
                alerts();
            }
            else {
                s.parentNode.innerHTML = "<nobr name='clear'>&nbsp</nobr>";
            }
        }
        else{
            s.parentNode.innerHTML = "<nobr name='clear'>" + s.value + "</nobr>";
        }
    }
    function clears() {
        var g = window.prompt("Remove all values from sudoku:","1");
        if(g != null) {
            $("#sudoku"+g+" [name='clear']").html("");
        }
    }
    function alerts() {
        $("#alert").parent().animate({backgroundColor: 'red'},"fast");
        $("#alert").parent().animate({backgroundColor: 'white'},"slow",killid());
    }
    function killid() {
        $("#alert").removeAttr("id");
    }
</script>
```

The id is added and then removed almost instantly after that. The background color does not change.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you try this in jsfidle

Comment: @AlexShilman It's running on my webserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are calling the function right when you are starting the animation. Remove the parentheses after the function name to let the `animate` method call it instead:

```
$("#alert").parent().animate({ backgroundColor: 'white' }, "slow", killid);
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. The id appears, it waits, then it disappears. Nothing happens to the td element.

Comment: In Google Chrome, if I manually apply a background-color element, it displays the background color but the code doesn't work.

Comment: @user3105700: Do you have a plugin to make color animations work?

Comment: No plugin. To manually add the background-color element, I used to "Inspect Element" tool. And by the way, nice catch in my coding. I didn't realize it would call the function if I coded it that way.